# What javascript patterns are used to create single functions that accept different parameters types?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Working in JS for some time now, I noticed a common feature with some JS libraries (eg. jQuery,  momentJS, Vue). They usually expose single function that can accept different parameters, both in terms of parameter type and in terms of number of parameters.

For example, let's say there is a `foo` function exposed by `fooLib`. I can use this same function in many ways such as:

```
import { foo } from './fooLib'

let a = foo('test') // pass string
let b = foo({ }) // pass object
let c = foo([]) // pass array
let d = foo('test', { }) // pass multiple parameters of different type
```

I've never written a JS library myself but sometimes I feel like it may be useful to create function like this in my app, although I am not aware what are the best practices in that case. I tried a few times to create something like this on the small scale by checking parameter types, but the code quickly got complex and unreadable.

So how is this accomplished in general? Are there some JS patterns for this type of programming?

Comment: Yes, there's no way around checking argument types. If your code becomes complex and unreadable, refactor by moving the smaller parts into separate helper functions - and notice that polymorphic/variadic functions that do many things at once are not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'll need to

(1) use `typeof` to check the types of the argument(s)

(2) In the function, define all possible arguments that may be passed (or use parameter rest syntax if the number of arguments is unlimited)

Something like:

```js
const foo = (...args) => {
  const filters = [];
  for (const arg of args) {
    if (typeof arg === 'string') filters.push(arg);
    else if (Array.isArray(arg)) filters.push(...arg);
    else if (arg && typeof arg === 'object') filters.push(Object.entries(arg));
  }
  console.log('foo doing something with:', filters);
};

foo('test') // pass string
foo({ someProp: 'someVal' }) // pass object
foo(['someArrayItem']) // pass array
foo('test', { anotherTestProp: 'anotherTestItem' }) // pass multiple parameters of different type
```

The logic *can* get a bit involved, but if the API is designed well, it doesn't have to be that difficult to implement or understand.